# 7809 Linear Voltage Regulator Outputs in Series

Tags: voltage-regulator, transformer, rectifier, lm78xx

I'm building a linear power supply that converts 120VAC mains voltage into multiple 9VDC, isolated outputs. I'm using [this transformer](https://taweber.powweb.com/store/wpdlxfmr2sch.jpg) that has the proper primary winding and 8 secondaries that I'll use for the 9VDC outputs. Each channel will look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGosSH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, I'll be making a couple of these, and I want one of them to have an 18V output. My first instinct was to wire two of the secondaries in series and use an LM317 to get the 18V like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjzHDg.png)</sup>

Then, I thought in order to avoid designing two PCBs and dividing my order (only making a few), I could just connect to of the 7809 outputs together to get 18V like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9z2dw.png)</sup>

At first glance, this seems ok. **Am I overlooking anything? Are there any nuances with the 7809s that would keep this from working? Am I forgetting something stupid?**

Comment: It should be OK but on light loads you might get a little bit of noise due to capacitive coupling between primary an secondary - you might want to put a 1nF cap from secondary 1 to secondary 2 - either pins.

Comment: looks fine, (ala Andy aka) the one thing you can't do is treat the mid-point in the second circuit as a ground with split supplies.

Comment: George, perhaps I should ask a separate question, but why could I not do split supplies? I understand it would be wise to use the 7909 if I wanted split supplies, but I never fully understood it. Is it just because the 7809 would be trying to regulate the reference instead of the negative voltage? I've always thought of linear regulators as "automatically adjusting potentiomenters" but perhaps I need to looks at the internal circuits more carefully?

Comment: Actually that is starting to make sense now that I've wrote it down. Is it bad because there is a regulator right in the middle of the reference? So my setup works because I'm not trying to get 9V out of schematic 3, but if I were, I would need a 7809/7909 combo?

Comment: The problem with doing a split supply is that the 78xx regulators only source current. If you draw more current from the positive side than the negative side, the "lower" regulator would have to sink current.

Comment: For a typical dual supply with one rectifier, I think you are right. However, with two separate rectifiers like this, I think a load on the positive side would never interact with U2. Current would return to BR1. In contrast, the only time a load would draw current through U1, U2, BR1, and BR2 is if it were connected like the voltmeter in the schematic. Make sense, or am I still missing something? I think whats confusing is two separate rectifiers. Such a configuration is typically useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work. Spreading the heat dissipation between two regulators may make things easier.

You may wish to put an inverse-parallel diode across each of the 9V outputs that you are going to series. The reason is that if you consider what happens when the output is short-circuited - there will be two regulators each trying to drive the other one negative and one will win. That may harm the regulator that's driven minus and it also could harm the output capacitors (if they're polarized types). Something like a 1N5403 would work fine.

Comment: Thank you, Spehro. I added diodes to the third schematic. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

It probably works, but it just feels wrong to me ;-) However, you could design a single PCB that can be used with either the 7809 or LM317. The difference is just the presence of R1 and R2 (and the regulators have a different pinout, but just take that into account in the PCB layout).

Comment: It's a real bummer the pinouts are different. Otherwise, this would be the way to go. I may still investigate. Space is a big factor though.